# Windows batch - character limit per command?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a problem. I don't know if I'm not doing something stupid, because I'm using bash in most cases. Windows Batch is totally different.

I want to generate arguments for mkvmerge, so firstly I'm dumping dir command to txt file, then I'm generating command for mkvmerge syntax and then again dumping it to txt file.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

dir /b /a-d fonts > temp_fn.txt
copy /y NUL temp_fn2.txt >NUL

set i=0
for /F %%a in (temp_fn.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set array[!i!]=%%a
)
set n=%i%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do <NUL set /p= --attachment-name !array[%%i]! --attachment-mime-type application/x-truetype-font --attach-file ^^^^"L:\fonts\!array[%%i]!^^" >> temp_fn2.txt

pause
```

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to import that file to variable and then test it with echo, a half of arguments (or rather characters) are stripped (from the end, more precisely - after 2024th character).

```
set /p args=<temp_fn2.txt
echo %args%
```

Are variables in batch somehow limited? Or maybe there is a better way to achieve it?

Comment: indeed, in  `cmd` there is a max size for variables (2047, iirc). And a max size of a command line (8191). And many other quirks. `Cmd` evolved from `CPM` for 8-bit computers and is more a collection of tools than a real language. If you want to use a really designed language, use Powershell.

Comment: As already pointed by Stephan, yes, there is a limit. You can place the `mkvmerge` options into a `.json` options file (command line argument will be something like `@options-file.json`). See [here](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.option_files)

Comment: @Stephan, environment variables can hold strings with up to 8191 characters (the limit was valid 2047 for Windows XP). `set /P` can read strings with up to 1023 characters...

Comment: The practical limit for SET /P is 1021, plus 2 characters for \r\n.

Comment: @aschipfl - Actually, XP also supports variables up to length 8191. It was Windows 2000 / Win NT 4.0 that was limited to 2047

Comment: @MCND thank you, options.json works like charm.